# How to consume a JSON data?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, cxf, jax-rs

Here is the method that handles the `add` call:

```
@POST
@Path("/add")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
String addUser(User user) {
  // ..... 
}
```

Since this URL is receiving a JSON, is there any way I can transform that JSON to a `User` object?

Comment: Yes. Read up on MessageBodyReaders, also http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-data-bindings.html#JAX-RSDataBindings-JSONsupport

Comment: seems kinda confusing at first. cna you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking for is just conversion of json into  object and no specific conversion behavior, just add a provider in your server. Use below in your configuration file.

```
<jaxrs:server ..... >
<jaxrs:providers>
<bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider">
</jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

Refer - http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/provider/json/JSONProvider.html